# How can legacy function returning PyObject * be integrated in a solution based on pybind11?

Tags: python, pybind11

Working on migrating from swig to pybind11 for exposing C++ to python.

One of the functions is implemented purely in basic Py* API such as PyDict_New, PyUnicode_FromString, PyDict_SetItemString. It returns a PyObject *, i.e.

```
PyObject *foo(const std::string& file) {
...
}
```

For now I would just like to reuse this piece of C. But how can I integrate that in the pybind11 solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pybind11 has a mechanism for dealing with such a case. See `reinterpret_steal`: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/include/pybind11/pytypes.h#L463.
In your example, assuming `foo` returns a `PyObject*` that points to a python string, you would call `pybind11::str str = pybind11::reinterpret_steal<pybind11::str>(foo("some string"))`. Be careful with object lifetimes and ownership here. `reinterpret_steal` will claim ownership of the object and will destruct it when the object it returns goes out of scope. If your code base already has a mechanism for managing ownership of python objects and you would like to keep that system in place, use `reinterpret_borrow` https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/include/pybind11/pytypes.h#L450 instead, which will not claim ownership of the underlying object.

Comment: Bham Thanks, I guessed there should be a mechanism. But could you elaborate a bit more, i.e. would one use add_object or something else to add it to the module and what would that code look like?

Comment: @user2052153 that depends on what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to expose a function to python called "foo" that will return a python object, like so `a = foo("abc")` ?